# How to Generate Crash Dump Analysis Report in Windows Environment

Tags: windows, windbg, crash-dumps

I am shipping a Software to end user. My Software consists of MFC and C#. when any process crashes i am automatically writing full dump to my logs folder. i would like to run another process which sniffs the log folder and analyzes the dump if any .dmp files written into this folder.

i know with the help of WinDbg we can manually analyze a dump file if we have all symbols.
but i wanted automate this procedure. 
can i call windbg from my code to analyze my dumps?

E.g. `int i=1/0`
above line in code crashed the code. and i got dump file.
now i should see a message that, that specific line caused the issue.

Comment: Well, for C#, this is very easy - just handle the exception. Usually, you'd do that as soon as you can reasonably handle it (ie. when it doesn't compromise the state of the application), but you can also have a global unhandled exception handler (`Application.ThreadException` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`). This will often be enough to find the error even without the dump. If you find yourself having to do an automatic dump analysis, your error handling code smells, even more so in .NET. And on localhost, you can attach a debugger on any unhandled exception in your code.

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. When I wrote the answer, I realized that it doesn't match the Stackoverflow rules, because: a) it shows little research effort. You could have found out how to start WinDbg and pass command line arguments. b) it is too broad. There are many ways of achieving what you want. c) it's either too hard to answer the question (providing what you really need) or too easy (strictly answering your question it would just be a "Yes"). Please read the tour, get familiar with StackOverflow and you'll benefit from it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to run an application that monitors the folder, so have a look at [FileSystemWatcher class (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).

Next you want to analyze dumps by calling WinDbg. You can start WinDbg using [Process.Start() (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can pass the dump name to WinDbg using the `-z` command line argument. In addition you can pass the `-c` command line argument to run some commands. Using `$<`, `$>`, `$><` or `$$><` you can even run commands which reside in another file. Note that for this approach your user needs to have WinDbg installed and you need to know the location of it in the file system. You probably can`t ship WinDbg with your application, because that's a licensing issue. All in all, not a very good approach.

A better option is to use [DbgHelp functions (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to directly operate on the dump file and not have the dependency on the complete WinDbg package. However, this might result in lot of work, especially because you need to decide whether it's a native exception (MFC part) or a .NET exception. In any case, to get the line number you would need to ship the PDBs of your application.

An even easier approach is to just catch the exception on Program level and output whatever you need. For many cases this should be sufficient to diagnose issues. At the end of the code I would just throw the exception so that the program actually crashes and you can still generate a crash dump in case you need it.

Be aware that this code is a bit dangerous, because `File.WriteAllText()` may not work in all circumstances, e.g. in case of an OutOfMemoryException, if the directory does not exist or the MFC part has corrupted your memory. You might also need to adapt this code to output the information from the `InnerException` property to not lose details.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        RunMyApp();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(exceptionLogFilename, 
            "Type: {0}\r\nMessage: {1}\r\nStacktrace:{2}\r\n",
            e.GetType().ToString(),
            e.Message,
            e.StackTrace);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Maybe you think again: how many exceptions do I expect? Can`t I analyze it in the debugger manually? Do I really need automated analysis? If I do automated analysis, will my tool be powerful enough to handle all the cases? Or will I end up in a situation where I use the debugger anyway?

Another hint: from your question description is seems like you have implemented your own unhandled exception handler. I think this approach is a bit outdated since we have [Windows Error Reporting LocalDumps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which can write full dumps to disk for later analysis.